# Bitstamp {"error": "API key not found"} Code Response: 200

Tags: java, web-services, base64

I am trying to place a balance request to Bitstamp in java, I wrote the following code but I am getting this error:

{"error": "API key not found"}
Code Response: 200

Anyone has an idea?

The key and the secret are the ones correctly provided by the exchange so now I wonder if I am making any mistake along the way.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String key    = "apiKeyDEMO";
    String secret = "apiSecretDEMO";
    Integer nonce  = 100;
    String ID = "123456";

    String message = nonce.toString() + ID + key;

    String signature = "";
    try {
        signature = encode(secret, message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    map.put("key", key);
    map.put("signature", signature);
    map.put("nonce", nonce.toString());

      StringBuilder urlParameters = new StringBuilder();

      for (String k : map.keySet()) {
          if(urlParameters.length() > 0) {
              urlParameters.append("&");
          }
          urlParameters.append(k).append("=").append(URLEncoder.encode(map.get(k)));
      }

      //System.out.println(urlParameters);


    try {
        doPost(map);
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

public static String encode(String secret, String message) throws Exception {

    Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
    sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
    byte[] hash = sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes());
    String signature = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hash).toUpperCase();

    //System.out.println(signature);

    return signature;

}


private static String doPost( Map<String,String> params) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {

    //"param1=a&param2=b&param3=c"
      StringBuilder urlParameters = new StringBuilder();

      for (String key : params.keySet()) {
         if(urlParameters.length() > 0) {
            urlParameters.append("&");
         }
         //urlParameters.append(key).append("=").append(URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key)));
         urlParameters.append(key).append("=").append(params.get(key));
      }


      String query = urlParameters.toString();

      System.out.println(query);


      URL url = new URL("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/balance/");

      HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

      //add reuqest header
      con.setRequestMethod("POST");

      // Send post request
      con.setDoOutput(true);
      DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
      wr.writeBytes(query);
      wr.flush();
      wr.close();


      String json = "";
      if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
         InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
         String text;
         while((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
            json += text;
         }
         br.close();
      }else{
         ;
      }
      con.disconnect();
      System.out.println("Code Response: " + con.getResponseCode());
      return json;


   }
```

}

Comment: did you ever find this? I'm having the same issue using the XChange library which used to work (before the new API look on bitstamp, may be related)

Answer (score 15):

Did you remember to click activate next to the key on the API page?

Comment: Sure I did! 
I found the solution but I rewrote the whole thing.